# Are dedicated std::vectors on the heap threadsafe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, containers, thread-safety, stdvector

This should be a simple question, but I'm having difficulty finding the answer.

If I have multiple std::vectors on the heap which are only accessed by *one thread each* are they thread-safe?  That is, because the vectors will be dedicated to a particular thread, I am only concerned about memory access violations when the vectors resize themselves, not about concurrent accesses, data races, etc.

Of course I could just stick each vector on its thread's stack, but they will be very large and could cause a stack overflow in my application.

Thanks!

Comment: The rule is: If you have a shared object accessed between threads, and at least one of those threads is a writer, then you need synchronization. Without that you have data race which is undefined behavior.

Comment: `std::vector` itself is quite small, only 24 bytes in [this](https://godbolt.org/z/6KGYx5Tv9) implementation. The majority of the data is stored in dynamic memory anyway.

Comment: Re, "If I have multiple...which are only accessed by one thread each, are they thread-safe?" The question is meaningless. "Thread-safe" is something we want to know about objects that are shared by more than one thread. An object is "thread-safe" if it's guaranteed to behave in some predictable/reasonable/documented way when it is accessed by more than one thread in the same process. Sounds like what you really want to know is whether the C++ `new` and `delete` operators are thread safe. (I'm pretty sure, Yes, but I can't actually cite any authority that says so.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access to different objects is thread-safe, `new` used by `std::vector`'s allocator is of course thread-safe too.

> Of course I could just stick each vector on its thread's stack, but they will be very large and could cause a stack overflow in my application.

I think you misunderstand how `vector` works. The object itself contains just a few pointers, that's it. The memory is allocated from the dynamic storage(heap) almost always. Unless you override it with your own allocator and use `alloca` or similar dangerous stuff.

So if you do

```
std::vector<int> local_variable{1,2,3,4};
```

The memory for the three pointers inside `local_variable` will be on stack but `1,2,3,4` objects are on the heap.

Comment: OOh!  Yes, I DID misunderstand.  I did not know that the actual memory it points to is on the heap.  That's great news!

Comment: @RoyGNEU `std::array` would be more akin to your idea. If made local, it allocates everything on stack, hence the fixed size.